# HTML+CSS: How to add arrow to horizontal menu items?

Tags: html, css

This is how looks like the item in menu bar without hover:
[image]

Here is with hover effect:
[image]

And here is the arrow that I am trying to add:
[image]

My current CSS formulas looks like:

```
ul.profile_menu {
    background: url('menu.png') repeat-x;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    
    li {
        display: inline;
        a {
            float: left;
        }
        a:hover {
            background: url('active_item.png') repeat-x;
                    height: 45px;
        }
    }   
}
```

But how to add the arrow on the bottom of active item?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at this: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: why don't you use the image containing that arrow. Or you will need to use CSS3. as @techfoobar suggested.

Comment: make a image with triangle facing bottom and add it as background of ul ;)

Comment: @techfoobar add it as answer!

Comment: but @techfoobar also gave a good pure css idea!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate the arrow (for current) purely using CSS itself (no CSS3 specific stuff - compatible with all browsers).

Use this site to generate the CSS you need for your arrow: http://cssarrowplease.com

Comment: its not working with all the browsers ! its CSS3 :-/ But +1 for the link !! :)

Comment: whats `pointer-events: none;`? is that a CSS1/2? and does it work for you in every browser? Did you check it?

Comment: and `RGBA color values are only supported in IE9+, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari, and in Opera 10+.`

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` is not needed of the arrow. Regarding `RGBA(..)`, thats not CSS3 either. But `position: xyz;` inside `:after` and `:before` wont work before CSS3. So you're right it has *some* CSS3 elements in it :-) We can work it out to be totally CSS2 compatible however.

Comment: to be honest, i dont know for what it is needed as i am not a master at CSS and i am `zero` at CSS3 !! :D

Comment: We are all newbies in this world of ever changing specs.. :0)